# MinGW: Use __declspec(dllexport) or __attribute__((visibility("default")))?

Tags: c, dll, mingw, shared-libraries

Does MinGW support `__declspec(dllexport)`/`__declspec(dllimport)`? Even if it does, should I rather use `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`? Basically should I decide what to use based on the platform or the compiler?

Should it be like this?

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   ifdef MYLIB_EXPORTS
#       define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define MYLIB_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif
```

Or like this?

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#   ifdef MYLIB_EXPORTS
#       define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define MYLIB_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif
```

And what about things like `__declspec(align(16))` Vs. `__attribute__((aligned(16)))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visibility Vs. dllexport is a platform thing, not a compiler thing. So using `__declspec(dllexport)`/`__declspec(dllimport)` (or `__attribute__((dllexport))`/`__attribute__((dllimport))`) with MinGW is the way to go. See:
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility#How_to_use_the_new_C.2B-.2B-_visibility_support

Answer (score 0):

Yes MinGW supports __declspec dllimport/dllexport (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). You should use it, if it makes easier to support multiple compilers.
In general compiler specific attributes are not portable, and you should use macro wrappers (as in your example).

Comment: So I should use the 2nd example?