# Preprocessor definition for __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++, mingw, cross-platform, c-preprocessor, declspec

Is it possible to define this as a preprocessor definition? I'm trying to do this:

```
#if defined _WIN32
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT
#endif
```

so that I can build this library for both Mac and Windows. There's a function which needs a `__declspec(dllexport)` when it's on Windows, but I don't need it when I'm building on Mac. So this is what I tried doing.

As I suspected, it gives me an error when building because it doesn't like the parenthesis, yet I've seen other people do it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350202/check-a-declspec-macro-in-preprocessor). Is there something I'm doing wrong or another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Edit: here's the error I get when trying to build on Windows (haven't tried on Mac yet).

```
 error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   38 | #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
      |                          ^
note: in expansion of macro 'DLL_EXPORT'
   94 | extern "C" DLL_EXPORT int process(const float* inputData, float* outputData)
      |            ^~~~~~
```

And I use mingw gcc to compile.

Comment: *"it gives me an error"*. where? on Mac? on Windows?

Comment: do you use visual studio, gcc or clang

Comment: Depending in the problem (which is currently unclear), maybe this is the solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166565/detect-gcc-as-opposed-to-msvc-clang-with-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166565/detect-gcc-as-opposed-to-msvc-clang-with-macro)

Comment: I've added the error in the post, and I'm cross compiling from ubuntu to windows using mingw-w64 gcc.

Comment: So your real problem is using `__declspec(dllexport)` with  `mingw`

Comment: This may be a solution although it says mingw supports this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285240/mingw-use-declspecdllexport-or-attribute-visibilitydefault

Comment: @drescherjm That's not the problem since we've always had __declspec(dllexport). It's just recently that we're doing a build for Mac, so we're trying to remove it for when we're building with Mac. Or maybe you're telling me that it was never the right way to do it using mingw even if it works...?

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not sure about that last link, he's doing something similar to me but it's not working on my side.

Comment: You probably need to back away from your current project and create a small minimal example code that reproduces the issue. For example does just adding `#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)` to the top of a "Hello World" program give you the same error when compiled using `mingw`. If you find something this may help your question get solved.

Comment: Seems like just adding the definition is fine, it builds correctly. The problem is with my usage of it then. I think it's unclear how I'm using so here: 
`DLL_EXPORT int myFunction(const float* input)`. Just in case I also tried with `DLL_EXPORT(dllexport) int myFunction(const float* input)`, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: The error messages refer to a macro named `EXTERN` which you have not described.   Odds are, you're trying to be a bit more (ummm) clever with macros than you have shown in your question.   And some of that cleverness that you haven't shown contributes to the effects you are seeing.    Rather than providing only code that you think is relevant and forcing others to guess about code you haven't shown, try providing a [mcve].

Comment: That was my fault when adding the error output, originally it was called `EXTERN` but changed it to `DLL_EXPORT` to make the question easier to understand, sorry about that! I just fixed it.

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` is a msvc stuff, not a win32 stuff. You shouldn't have `__declspec(dllexport)` for gcc on windows.

Comment: @Jarod42 this doesn't work since we're using this .dll with an app we build using msvc later on. If I remove `__declspec(dllexport)` I get an error about there being no entry point to the function I need to put `__declspec(dllexport)` when I try to run the application that depends on this library.

Comment: You need `__declspec(dllimport)` msvc side when compiling with. (gcc export all by default).

Comment: Are you trying to export class member functions?